In a batch file, how to handle ")" character in the input of a for loop?
I need to loop through every word in a line of text and get the last word.
I use the following code to do it.
for %%a in (%_IFLE_input%) do ( set _IFLE_last_token=%%a )

_IFLE_last_token= now contains the last word.
However I just hit a word that contains the ) character and that stops the script with error

Close) was unexpected at this time.


The Text was Left)Close
I tried putting the input variable in quotes
for %%a in ("%_IFLE_input%") do ( set _IFLE_last_token=%%a )

But then %%a is just the entire string, spaces and all.
Is there a proper way to quote the string so that for will loop through each word but without breaking the for loop syntax on characters like ) ?
Only option that I see, is to filter out all poison characters and then them into spaces.
Is there a better way, in batch ?  (Or using the external tools available to a unupdated windows 10 22h2 )

PowerShell comes standard on Windows machines and can do what you want without the trouble that comes with cmd's lack of distinction between data and code.

Yes, the powershell would be
for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%a in (powershell -command "'%_IFLE_input%'.Split(' ')[-1]") do set _IFLE_last_token=%%a
but I want to do it in pure batch

Well, you said "Or using the external tools available to a unupdated windows 10 22h2", which includes PowerShell. Your requirements are totally determined by you.

You are right, powershell is one of those. I asked imprecisely. I meant tools like findstr, fc  or certutil. Things that might still work on dos 6.22 or win95.

do you actually expect findstr.exe or certutil.exe to exist in DOS or Win95? If you want maximum (theoretical) compatibility, perhaps you should set the bar at XP or 2000. Anything prior to that, and you can't even expect cmd.exe to behave the same.

You are right, I tried win95 cmd and even the long label names I use don't work.  I am curious if it might be possible to backport cmd.exe and the other .exe from w2k back to win9x. I've seen someone make dotnet work on win95 so maybe it's possible. But yeah, targetting w2k is more resonnable. I also prefer to keep by script pure batch. I find them less intimidating to share than powershell plus there is less likely to be group policies to stop the execution of batch files than powershell on user-only computers.

Another way to process the problematic string is delayed expansion (the variable is expanded after parsing the line, preventing the syntax error.
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "var=Left)Close"
for %%a in (!var!) do ( set "last=%%a" )
set last

Note: this way you get problems when the string contains one or more !.
As you speak of "every line in a text file":
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "var=Left!Close"
for /f "delims=" %%x in (test.txt) do (
  for %%a in (%%x) do ( set "last=%%a" )
  echo !last!
)


Thank you this works. I feel this is the "standard" answer and I accept it. However @squashman's answer is more spectacular. Wish I could accept both with comments

SET "last=%%~a"

This awkward-looking syntax is how you (try to) prevent cmd.exe from treating the data in %%a as code. The ~ strips away surrounding quotes from %%a, which is a safeguard when using the quotes to protect the contents of the variable.
Even this won't keep you totally safe from all special characters all the time. cmd.exe has some serious limitations when it comes to text/string processing and this is one of them.

Here is a technique that uses string substitution to assign the first and last words to variables. The code can be extended to assign every word to an array of variables if needed.
@echo off & setlocal
rem http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6429

set "_IFLE_input=A long sentence) with lots of word(s) and stuff!"
set "_IFLE_first_token=%_IFLE_input: =" & set "_IFLE_last_token=%"
echo First word: %_IFLE_first_token%
echo Last word: %_IFLE_last_token%

endlocal

Output
D:\My Drive\BatchFiles\SO\78389129>so.bat
First word: A
Last word: stuff!

Another option is to surround each space delimited term with quotes.
@echo off & setlocal

set "_IFLE_input=A long sentence) with lots of word(s) and stuff!"
for %%G in ("%_IFLE_input: =" "%") do ( set _IFLE_last_token=%%~G )
echo Last word: %_IFLE_last_token%
endlocal

Output
D:\My Drive\BatchFiles\SO\78389129>so3.bat
Last word: stuff!


Thank you for pointing these out. This wizardry is still above my pay grade ! But I confirm it works just fine ! I wonder if I could build proper concatenate and split functions out of these !

Does the batch file programming community have a name for this technique ?

@Shodan it is basic string substitution.

I mean it's more than that, it's running command injection in the substitution. %_IFLE_input: =" & set "_IFLE_last_token=%

I mean the following, specifically %_IFLE_input: =" & set "_IFLE_last_token=%
